# Ampersand conversion in JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, serialization

When I Serialize an Object using `JavaScriptSerializer`, it is converting '&' to unicode value '\u0026'

```
{
  [
    {
      "fContext": "Claim",
      "fKey": "Number",
      "fValue": "azt\u0026",
      "fType": null,
      "fLevel": null,
      "fHelp": null
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` it is not converting it. Any settings to skip in `JavaScriptSerializer` too.

```
{
  [
    {
      "fContext": "Claim",
      "fKey": "Number",
      "fValue": "azt&",
      "fType": null,
      "fLevel": null,
      "fHelp": null
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the object with '&'

### [image: Object Image]

Serialized Object with Unicode

[image: Serialized Object]

Comment: Same thing... Both are valid....

Comment: JSON allows for either the `&` character or the unicode number. See json.org

Comment: I need JavaScriptSerializer not to convert '&' to Unicode. How to achieve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I define a class as follows: `var root = new { fContext = "Claim", fKey = "Number", fValue = "azt&" };` and then serialize with `var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(root);` the ampersand is not escaped.  Can you provide a [mcve] showing how you serialize?

Comment: I have attached the Image with code and output

Comment: I am having a similar issue when deserializing a Json object. In my database, the customer has English&Spanish. When I deserialize the object using JavaScriptSerializer, it comes up as Englishu0026Spanish. Nothing appears to work for me, so I write an extension method to do a find and replace.

Comment: I don't want to find and replace since we don't know what are the other symbols affected like this. Is it a bug in the API. If I use JsonConvert it is working fine.